# Get data from Firebase Realtime Database stopped working in React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I created a `React Native application` that uses `Firebase` for authentication and for `database`.
My piece of code that returns data from `database`:

```
database.ref('/Membership').on('value', querySnapShot => {
            let array = []
            let data = querySnapShot.val()
            let keys = Object.keys(data)
            keys.forEach(key => {
                array.push(data[key])
            })

            setMemberships(array)
        })
```

My `database`:

[image]

My problem is that this piece of code worked for my data, but it stopped working. Database in still on, I have access to it, it throws no error.

I don't know what's the problem because there is no error thrown. If I try to `console.log` the `database.ref('/Membership')` it gets the correct path, but on the `on` function nothing happens, not even a console.log.

The version of firebase used is `"^9.6.10"`

Can somebody help me? Thank you for your time!

### Edit with solution

Sorry for creating a post, but maybe will help someone one day.

With some kind of update (or I don't know why), my `database rules` have been changed so I had no permission to `write or read`. So I changed them back to `true` and it's working.